# Will it affect the chances of permanent residency in Australia if I visa over stay in USA?

Tags: usa, visa, australia, overstay

I overstayed my visa in USA after entering legally and working for three years. Now, I have a job offer in Australia and I'm looking for permanent residency. Will my past affect the future now?

Comment: Were you deported from the USA or otherwise banned/noticed? Did you leave when you were told to?

Comment: No, I have never been deported/  asked to leave from US and still living here. I want to start over in Australia and would like to know it will be an issue with the AUS consulate interview as I'm going to have it here.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know. Did the visa application ask about your current immigration status? I worry because you are committing a crime right now, even though you haven't been caught. Ah, here's someone in a [similar situation](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/overstayed-my-us-visa-for-over-9-years-never-got-deported-can-i-return-as-a-to) and she did manage to emigrate.